# Using an array list of arrays in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a hash table that is an array list (length 100) of ArrayList. Each worker has an ID number, name, and salary. I have created an array list of size 100 of array lists and want to store each worker at the index IDNumber%100. For example, John Doe, whose ID is 9999, would be stored at the index 99. In the case of collisions, like Jean Doe whose ID number is 19999, she would be stored in the array list within the array list also at index 99. When I print out my hash table prints out the worker information multiple time like so:

```
John Smith             234         65678.5
Janice Sullivan           27854        29345.75
Javier Lopez           10765         87687.1
Jill Applewood           22234         38678.0
Jake Drake            1234        22222.25
John Doe            9999        100000.0
Jean Doe           19999        100001.0
John Smith             234         65678.5
Ect.
```

Do I have a problem with my printing method or am I not properly creating the hash table?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PartnerHash
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Worker workers[] = {new Worker("John Smith", 65678.50, 234),
                new Worker ("Janice Sullivan", 29345.75, 27854),
                new Worker ("Javier Lopez", 87687.10, 10765),
                new Worker ("Jill Applewood", 38678.00, 22234),
                new Worker ("Jake Drake", 22222.25, 1234),
                new Worker ("John Doe", 100000.00, 9999),
                new Worker ("Jean Doe", 100001.00, 19999)};

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Worker>>    list =populateHashTable(workers);
        print(list);
    }
    private static void print(ArrayList<ArrayList<Worker>> list) 
    {
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            if (list.get(i)!=null)
                for (int j=0; j<list.get(i).size(); j++)
                {
                    if (list.get(i).get(j)!=null)
                        {
                            System.out.print(list.get(i).get(j).getName());
                            System.out.printf("%16s",list.get(i).get(j).getIDNum());
                            System.out.printf("%16s",list.get(i).get(j).getSalary());
                            System.out.println("");
                        }
                }
        }
    }
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Worker>> populateHashTable(Worker [] workers) 
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Worker>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Worker>>(100);
        ArrayList<Worker> sublist = new ArrayList<Worker>();
        for (int j=0; j<100; j++)
            list.add(sublist);
        for (int i=0; i<workers.length; i++)
        {
            int index =workers[i].getIDNum()%100;
            ArrayList target=list.get(index);
            target.add(workers[i]);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: While not at issue here, I am confused about your choice of where to use `{` and not (some have none, some have one, some have two).  There's also the import of `import java.lang.reflect.Array` which made me raise my eyebrows at the top.  That's likely a red herring, but I'd strongly suggest that you re-evaluate your code and let the IDE help you as much as it can in pointing out unused imports, missing braces, and unnecessary braces.

Comment: Didn't you ask here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612056/creating-and-printing-a-hash-table-in-java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem

So looking at this section of the code:

```
ArrayList<Worker> sublist = new ArrayList<Worker>();
    for (int j=0; j<100; j++)
        list.add(sublist);
```

If you think about what that is doing, essentially you have created ***one*** sublist, then adding that ***exact same*** sublist 100 times to your list.

Then when you get to the next loop

```
for (int i=0; i<workers.length; i++)
{
    int index =workers[i].getIDNum()%100;
    ArrayList target=list.get(index);
    target.add(workers[i]);
}
return list;
```

You are literally adding every worker to `sublist` `workers.length` times.  That is why when you go to "print" your arrays you are seeing:

> When I print out my hash table prints out the worker information multiple time

*(which by the way are not hash tables..)*

#### Solution

If you really want to continue using `ArrayList<ArrayList<Worker>>` then create a **new** arraylist for each sublist:

```
//ArrayList<Worker> sublist = new ArrayList<Worker>(); <- get rid of this
    for (int j=0; j<100; j++)
        list.add(new ArrayList<Worker>());
```

That way when you add the workers in you actually get different instances of sublists.

Or you can consider just using the built in `HashMap<Integer, Worker>` with the workers `ID` as the key's and then `Worker` as the value

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same sublist to your main list 100 times so each worker you add appears to get added to each hash 'bucket'. Change the code in the populating method like this:

```
// ArrayList<Worker> sublist = new ArrayList<>(); remove this line!
for (int j=0; j<100; j++) {
    list.add(new ArrayList<Worker>());
}
```